# Datagridview show only last record although I have more rows when compare currentreading excel and invoice table

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, oledb

**Problem**

Datagridview show only last record although I have more rows when  currentreading excel is less than currentreading  invoice table .

Wrong result in else statement of btn_import click inside for loop count

**Details**

I have excelsheet as following :

```
unitcode   CurrentReading
12          2000
14          4500
```

and I have table Invoice in database in sql server 2012 has following fields

```
serial     unitcode       CurrentReading   year  month
  1           12                 1000      2018   3
  3           14                 5000      2018   3
```

so that how to display unit code 14 in datagridview .

Actually what i need is when currentreading for unit code in excel sheet is less than currentreading
in table invoice display the values in datagridview .
the formula as following

btn import that import from excel

```
private void btn_import_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)                               
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dt = Showdataprint();
        decimal LastMeterReading = ConvertToDecimal(GetLastReading(dt.Rows[i]["UnitCode"].ToString()));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[i]["CurrentMeterReading"].ToString()) && ConvertToDecimal(dt.Rows[i]["CurrentMeterReading"]) > 0 && ConvertToDecimal(dt.Rows[i]["CurrentMeterReading"]) > ConvertToDecimal(LastMeterReading))
        {
            //insert to table invoice
        }
        else
        {
            System.Data.DataTable dtErrorRows = new DataTable();
            DataView  dv2 = new DataView(dt);
            dv2.RowFilter = "(CurrentMeterReading < " + LastMeterReading + ")" + "and" + "(UnitCode = " + Utilities.ObjectConverter.ConvertToInteger(dt.Rows[i]["UnitCode"]) + ")";
            dv2.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.CurrentRows;
            int a = dv2.Count;
            if (dv2.Count > 0)
            {
                dtErrorRows = dv2.ToTable();
            }                                       
        }
    }
    Grid.DataSource = dtErrorRows;
}
```

function get data from excel

```
public System.Data.DataTable Showdataprint()
{
    string connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";", txtpath.Text);
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    con.Open();
    string str = @"SELECT    [UnitCode],[CurrentMeterReading] FROM  [Sheet5$] ";
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
    com = new OleDbCommand(str, con);
    OleDbDataAdapter oledbda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    oledbda = new OleDbDataAdapter(com);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = new DataSet();
    oledbda.Fill(ds, "[Sheet5$]");
    con.Close();
    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
    dt = ds.Tables["[Sheet5$]"];
    return dt;
}
```

For selecting currentreading from Invoice Table :

```
private decimal GetLastReading(string UnitCode)
{
    string sqlquery = "";
    sqlquery = @"select isnull((select top 1 CurrentMeterReading from WAHInvoice where UnitCode=" + UnitCode + " order by year , Serial desc),0)";
    object nullableValue = DataAccess.ExecuteScalar(sqlquery);
    decimal myValue;
    if (nullableValue == null || nullableValue == DBNull.Value)
    {
        myValue = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        decimal.TryParse(nullableValue.ToString(), out myValue);
    }
    return Utilities.ObjectConverter.ConvertToDecimal(DataAccess.ExecuteScalar(sqlquery));
}
```

Expected Result in datagridview

```
unitcode   CurrentReading

14          4500
```

Comment: Did you debug the code and identify what could be issue?

Comment: The code is barely readable. Please format it, use indents.